# Android Studio - Error de diseño con Drawer Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, viewpager

**Descripción del problema:**

Tengo un layout en el cual estoy intentando pegar un **Bar layout** en la parte inferior (bottom). Este layout debe tener por encima de la Bar layout, un **View Pager** que abarque desde el principio de arriba (top) hasta donde empieza el bar layout.

**Que intenté hacer?**

Para lograr esto, intenté crear una restricción vertical de la parte inferior del view pager con la parte superior del bar layout y le asigné un **layout_height="0dp"** a mi view pager para que actúe como un **match_constraint**. El problema es que el view pager se tomó en serio los 0dp haciendo que esa sea la altura del view pager, en lugar de estirarlo hacia abajo.

**Adjunto una representación gráfica del problema:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero que mi layout quede como en la **Foto 2** pero me está quedando como en la **Foto 1**.

**Adjunto el código de mi diseño**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.ui.CHAT.fragment_contenedor_chat"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_datos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pagerr_perfil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bar_layout"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabss_perfil"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ayuda"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#03a9f4"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Es necesario el uso de `ConstraintLayout`? Porque de no ser así se puede reemplazar el `LinearLayout` y el `ConstraintLayout` por un `RelativeLayout` (yo recomendaría también que el `DrawerLayout` no tenga tantos elementos anidados, esto de manera a mejorar la legibilidad del código y siempre va a ser más fácil la modificación mientras menos anidados estén los elementos).

Con el uso del `RelativeLayout` se consigue lo que buscás.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:contentDescription="Ayuda">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabss_perfil"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#03a9f4"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pagerr_perfil"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="Ayuda"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/bar_layout"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Que bien!!! Tu código es muy simple y funciona. Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda!